# Access GET variables with PHP + .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I'm developing a website using PHP.
My .htaccess has this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]*)\.html$ book.php?title=$1 [L]
```

So the URL that looked like: www.example.com/book.php?title=title-of-the-book
turns into www.example.com/book/title-of-the-book.html

In a specific case, from another page in the site, I want to link to pages like this:
www.example.com/book.php?title=title-of-the-book?myfield=1
that then turns into 
www.example.com/book/title-of-the-book.html?myfield=1.html

Being ther, I cannot acces the GET variables using the usual PHP way

```
$variable = $_GET['myfield']
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify `[QSA]` (Query string append) so you may pass a query string after your url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]*)\.html$ book.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

PS: Why are you using `*` here? Wouldn't `+` suit better?

Comment: I don't know about the `*` and `+` . I don't understand very much about URL rewritin, so a friend of mine wrote these rules for me. Why do you think there should be a  `*` instead of a `+` ?

Comment: `*` is zero or more characters, i.e. `book/.html` would be allowed, too. `+` is one or more characters, so `book/.html` wouldn't be matched.